# SQL ORACLE Average Price

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables **"suppliers"** **"products"** **"categories"**

-The **"suppliers"** table contains

```
SUPPLIERID, COMPANYNAME, CONTACTNAME,
 CONTACTTITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION,
 POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, PHONE, FAX, HOMEPAGE
```

-The **"products"** table contains

```
PRODUCTID, PRODUCTNAME, SUPPLIERID,
 CATEGORYID, QUANTITYPERUNIT,
 UNITPRICE, UNITSINSTOCK, UNITSONORDER, 
REORDERLEVEL, DISCONTINUED
```

-The **"categories"** table contains

```
CATEGORYID, CATEGORYNAME, DESCRIPTION, PICTURE
```

**I need to obtain a list of names of countries that supply products in the 'Seafood' category. Show only those with the average price greater than 10**

I try this:

```
SELECT  country 
FROM suppliers JOIN products USING (supplierid) JOIN CATEGORIES  USING (categoryid)
WHERE LOWER (categoryname)='seafood' AND HAVING  AVG(unitprice)>10 ;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY country`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` clause and do not want the `AND` before the `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT  country 
FROM    suppliers
        JOIN products USING (supplierid)
        JOIN CATEGORIES  USING (categoryid)
WHERE   LOWER (categoryname)='seafood'
GROUP BY country
HAVING  AVG(unitprice)>10;
```